# Simulate multi user cluster

Tags: matlab, simulator, multi-user

I have to simulate a system ( Allocation of memory in multi-user shared memory system) like this:

some nodes as a master and workers and multi users that can run application on these nodes. I have to implement a page replacement policy similar to LRU but more complicated and evaluate it. In short, I focus on allocation policies for multi-user in-memory file-systems.
My question is:

1. Is it possible in MATLAB? If yes, how do I start to do this?
2. Is there another better simulator for this system?

Comment: What type of simulation are you trying to implement? Discrete event simulation?

Comment: event-driven simulation to study performance of different policies with different workloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to go:

1. Use SIMEVENTS, a simulink toolbox to do this.
2. Use Matlab without any toolbox. Start with the wikipedia article about discrete event simulation. It contains all knowledge you need to implement a simple discrete event simulator.